# Value of optional type UILabel not unwrapped.

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to populate a table with one section and 5 rows. I get a "Value of optional type UILabel not unwrapped". I'm pretty sure my syntax is wrong or archaic. Please advise.

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
    {

        var cell = UITableViewCell()
        cell.textLabel.text = "Hello"
        return cell

    }
```

Comment: `textLabel` is optional, so you would have to do `cell.textLabel?.text = "Hello"`.  You should also look up the correct way to dequeue table cells if that is your real code.

Comment: @dan Thanks Dan. After doing that it says variable 'cell' was never mutated. Pardon my ignorance.

Comment: That's because you declared it as `var` when you should have declared it as `let` since you aren't changing it

Comment: @dan No more errors. But for some reason, the cells aren't populated with "Hello".

Comment: did you set the data source and delegate of your tableview??

Comment: @dan I actually forgot to connect it to delegate. It works after connecting. Many thanks, guys! I appreciate the help. I'm new to this.

Answer (score 0):

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
{ 
var cell = UITableViewCell() cell.textLabel!.text = "Hello" 
return cell 
}
```

One more thing as you are saying that cell is not showing "hello" text.
Please check cell type